# 80's/90's Live-action Sci-fi TV series: group of kids find an alien

Tags: story-identification

All I can remember from this was that it really freaked me out when I was seven, we watched it in class once- it may have been an educational thing, so possibly made by the BBC, but then again it might have been American... judging from the multicoloured clothes, I think it was made in the 80's/90's- that was what I thought at the time anyway.

I think some kids find an alien (kinda grey and fat-ish in appearance- obviously a man in a suit), and the alien has some kind-of device in his hand that's counting down, like a bomb.

There may have been another (bigger?) alien searching for the one the kids found, because I can remember one of the boys commenting "oh, the big alien's searching for him!", but this may have been a misinterpretation.

Towards the end of the first episode, I can remember the camera cuts to an/the alien that's on a beach littered with rubbish, and a bridge behind him. The alien's looking at the watch/timer in his hand and it's beeping dramatically before it cuts to the credits.

I think we watched more, because when the next episode started up I remember feeling annoyed at the anti-climax, but I can't actually remember what happened.

There was something about the kids going into a forest too, and in some kinda cabin (although it might have been a spaceship), there were loads of buttons and lights and something spinning on the wall behind them (which I stared at for a while and entirely ignored the conversation the main characters were having).

I can remember there were maybe five kids/teenagers, one blonde girl wearing a light-blue t-shirt, maybe some boy called Billy with a red hat (but I'm not sure)...

Comment: Few questions: What year did you watch this/were you seven? Was this live-action or animated? Was the tone serious like E.T. or more like a TV sitcom? Also, as much detail as you can give on the two aliens' appearances will help greatly.

Comment: You've definitely found it, but 2007.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds a bit like "[**Earth Warp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Warp)", which was an educational show that aired on the BBC back in 1994. The show was created to teach children about pollution, and did indeed include a scene with a trash-covered beach. The alien is not grey, but otherwise matches:

[image]

The alien, Ollie, came to Earth because a probe his people launched years ago activated and will destroy the oceanfront town of Southbeach unless it is deactivated. He carries a ball-like device that monitors the probe's countdown and heals people.

When he lands, he is discovered by three local children who hide him & offer to help find the probe. In later episodes, they are joined by two more children. I don't remember a second alien pursuing him, though.

Comment: That's definitely it, thank you so much! It was driving me crazy wondering :D (have to wait 20 hours to "award bounty", but will do it ASAP :)

Comment: @MikasaPinata - no problem. We specialize in finding obscure TV shows like this.